# Type Aliases in Rust

Tags: alias, rust

How exactly does type aliasing work in Rust?

I've been examining breakage in some old Rust code I didn't write and noticed that `Thunk::new(...)` causes this error:

```
  error: type `Box<alloc::boxed::FnBox<_, Output=_> + Send>` 
  does not  implement any method in scope named `new`
```

[Thunk](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thunk/type.Thunk.html) is defined as:

```
type Thunk<'a, A = (), R = ()> = Box<FnBox<A, Output=R> + Send + 'a>;
```

I thought `Alias::method` didn't work in previous versions of Rust? How should I change `Thunk::new` into something that works? Is it missing an import for `Box` or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Thunk::new` used to work because it [used to be](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/cade32acf6f5ff209ee082d70350d9bc0362985a#diff-8a31fda633b35e5267e3d3727e8e23cc) a `struct` rather than a type alias. This was changed two days ago:  [Add (unstable) FnBox trait as a nicer replacement for `Thunk`.](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/23939)

To fix this, replace `Thunk::new` with `Box::new`, as also done throughout the standard library in that PR. Also change `thunk.invoke()` to `thunk()`.